# Project Euler #4 with C#

Tags: c#, linq, palindrome

i'm trying to solve project euler #4 with c# and according to previous posts, i couldn't find any solution of this problem with c#.

The question is:

> A palindromic number reads the same both ways. The largest palindrome
> made from the product of two 2-digit numbers is 9009 = 91 99.
>
> Find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers.

Below is my code, but when i look how it flows, i can't see my mistake. How can i fix it?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace CS_11_project_Euler_problem_4
{

class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int x, y;
        string product="" , res="";

        for (x = 100; x <= 999; x++)
        {
            for (y = 100; y <= 999; y++)
            {
                product = Convert.ToString(x*y);

                if (product == new String(product.Reverse().ToArray()))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("X=" + x + " Y=" + y );
                    res = product;

                    Console.WriteLine("Polindrome is: " + res);
                }

                else { continue; }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

The result that my code found is 580085, Here is my output's screenshot. It displays every result palindrome number with its multipliers.

[image]

**Eventough according to projecteuler.net my result is not correct. One of my outputs was giving me the actual result. 906609 . It's the second result before my code's last palindrome. I think i was wrong to think increasing multiliers within nested for loops because it was unintentionally based on "biggest X gives biggest multiplier logic". In order to prevent it i'm going to convert my res and product to integer once more, and always keep the bigger product result in variable product**

Comment: Asking people to spot errors in your code is not especially productive.  You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to isolate the problem, by tracing the progress of your program, and comparing it to what you expect to happen.  As soon as the two diverge, then you've found your problem.   (And then if necessary, you should construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org).)

Comment: Well, thanks for kind criticism. Actually, at first i divided my code to some methods, and they all worked well but when i tried to combine them together i have no outputs at all. of course i can revise it, i'm also well aware of sscce but i thought it was obvious to see my problem hence the code is only 2 nested for loops and a while :)

so, if you can unvote for close flag, i 'll be appreciated

Comment: I appreciate that your code above is short, but you really ought to be able to tackle this with standard debugging techniques.  For example, add a print statement inside each of your loops.

Comment: Ok. I'll do it within next 5 minutes

Comment: So you had code nicely split into small functions and producing correct result, than you decided cobble it all together and it stop working? Sounds like good hint for using small clearly named well tested functions... Side note: there are plenty of sites with answer to the project - if you don't want to do it yourself just find and paste an answer.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I thought they were too small to be seperated but based on this experience, i now see splitting  makes is easier. Plus, i'm well aware of There are lots of sites gives the result. But why would i bother myself here if wanted just the result??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because once you do find a palindrome you are looping forever inside your while loop. Change the while to and if and it should work.

EDIT:

Yes, you will need to keep track of the largest product found so far, not simply assume the last product found is the largest.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. i changed while loop as you suggested. And added else statement after if which contains nothing but "continue;" reserved word. However according to projecteuler.net my result is not correct. Can you give me a hint about it?

Comment: The continue there essentially does nothing. Not sure why the answer is incorrect though.

Comment: @TimurAykutYıldırım Hint: `995 * 583 = 580085`.

Comment: Thats the answer I get when I run it.

Comment: What answer are you getting?

Comment: I get the same thing but 993 * 913 = 906609 . It's the second result before my code's last palindrome.

I think i was wrong to think increasing multiliers within nested for loops because it was unintentionally based on "biggest X gives biggest multiplier logic". The way it has to be is : "both multipliers has to get bigger as long as they can"

In order to prevent it i'm going to convert my res and product to integer once more, and always keep the bigger product result in variable product.

Thank you very much for your help my friend :)

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error and I was looking for help when I found this post. And your console screenshot helped me solve this.

As you can see, the official answer gets printed before your final answer. Note that the question asks you for the "largest" palindrome which happens to be 906609 and not 580085. Our program prints the latter because it goes according to the for loop and the last x for which palindrome check works is the value that gets printed.

I solved this by having an if condition(my code logic differs but I've adapted it to yours):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace CS_11_project_Euler_problem_4
{

class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int x, y;
        string product="" , res="";

        for (x = 100; x <= 999; x++)
        {
            for (y = 100; y <= 999; y++)
            {
                product = Convert.ToString(x*y);

                if (product == new String(product.Reverse().ToArray()))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("X=" + x + " Y=" + y );

                    if(x*y>Convert.ToInt64(res))
                        res = product;
                        Console.WriteLine("Polindrome is: " + res);
                }

                else { continue; }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

The if block checks if this product is greater than the previous one and if it is, prints. Hope this helps!

P.S: I had a very convoluted logic involving lists and checking each digit and stuff. Your string logic looks very elegant! Thanks!